# why first time null value come in autocomplete?

Tags: java, android, autocomplete

I make a simple demo of autocomplete in which every thing is running fine. But there is one problem when I write first character performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) constraint give null value but after that it gives the correct value. For example if I write "p" it gives null .Then if I write "pa" it gives the constraint "pa"..why it gives first time null value..
Secondly how to get click event of autocomplete list (I want to get the text of selected item )
here is my code ..

```
public class CustomAutocompletAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

        private String stationNameAndCodeValue;
        ArrayList<String> autolistArray;
        ArrayList<String> objects;
        private Context context;

        public CustomAutocompletAdapter(Context context, String[] autolistArray) {
                this.autolistArray = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < autolistArray.length; i++) {
                        this.autolistArray.add(autolistArray[i]);

                }
                this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
                return autolistArray.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
                return autolistArray.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = convertView;
                if (v == null) {
                        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_adapter, null);
                }

                final TextView stationNameAndCode = (TextView) v
                                .findViewById(R.id.item_selectStationName);

                stationNameAndCodeValue = autolistArray.get(position);

                stationNameAndCode.setText(stationNameAndCodeValue);

                return v;
        }

        Filter myFilter = new Filter() {

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                FilterResults results) {

                        System.out.println("Constraint " + constraint);
                        Log.d("-----------", "publishResults");
                        if (results.count > 0 && results != null) {
                                autolistArray = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } else {
                                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                        }

                }

                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                        Log.d("-----------", "performFiltering");
                        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                        List<String> filteredArrList = new ArrayList<String>();
                        if (objects == null) {
                                objects = new ArrayList<String>(autolistArray);
                        }
                        Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
                        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                                // set the Original result to return
                                results.count = objects.size();
                                results.values = objects;

                        } else {
                                constraint = (String) constraint.toString().toLowerCase(locale);
                                Pattern logEntry = Pattern.compile("-\\((.*?)\\)");
                                for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
                                        String name = objects.get(i);
                                        // System.out.println(name);

                                        Matcher matchPattern = logEntry.matcher(name);
                                        String subText = "";
                                        while (matchPattern.find()) {
                                                subText = matchPattern.group(1);
                                        }
                                        if (subText.toLowerCase(locale).contains(constraint)) {
                                                System.out
                                                                .println("CustomAutocompletAdapter.myFilter.new Filter() {...}.performFiltering()");
                                                filteredArrList.add(name);
                                        }
                                }
                                System.out.println(filteredArrList);
                                // set the Filtered result to return
                                results.count = filteredArrList.size();
                                results.values = filteredArrList;

                        }
                        return results;
                }

        };

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
                return myFilter;
        }
}
```

**Main activity :**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.select_station);

         autocompleteView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.item_autoComplete);

         STATION_LIST = new String[GlobalList.stationList.length
                                            + GlobalExtendStationList.stationList.length];
                                    System.arraycopy(GlobalList.stationList, 0, STATION_LIST, 0,
                                            GlobalList.stationList.length);
                                    System.arraycopy(GlobalExtendStationList.stationList, 0,
                                            STATION_LIST, GlobalList.stationList.length,
                                            GlobalExtendStationList.stationList.length);
                                    autosuggestAdapter = new CustomAutocompletAdapter(this,STATION_LIST);
                                    autocompleteView.setAdapter(autosuggestAdapter);
```

is there any update ?

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is because AutoCompleteTextView performs filtering only if characters count is greater then threshold (see [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.java#791)) and you can not assign this threshold less then 1. By default the threshold value is 2. If 1 character is enough for you, call

```
autocompleteView.setThreshold(1);
```

Otherwise you can subclass AutoCompleteTextView and override [setThreshold](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.java#490) method.